# UWP Images from my DataTemplate wont bind to my AdaptiveGirdView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I've being trying different ways to implement the Adaptive grid and filling it with my own images but no matter what I just get a blank screen.

I've tried the following, I get no errors but nothing shows up when I run it locally except the command bar:

Mainpage.xaml:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MobileAppProject"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:viewModels="using:ViewModels"
    xmlns:Controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    x:Class="MobileAppProject.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">


    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptTemplate" x:DataType="local:AdaptItem">
            <Grid
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1">
                <Image
                    Source="{Binding Image}"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="12,10,12,12">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                                   OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                                   ItemHeight="200"
                                   DesiredWidth="300"
                                   SelectionMode="Single"
                                   IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AdaptTemplate}"/>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,24,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}">

                        <CommandBar x:Name="cmdbar" 
                                    IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=isopentoggle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsSticky="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=isstickytoggle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    ClosedDisplayMode="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=combobox}">
                            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 1"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 2"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 3"/>
                                <AppBarButton Label="Menu Item 4"/>
                            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                            <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Accept"/>
                            <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Contact" Label="Contact"/>
                        </CommandBar>
                        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="Assets/storeLogo-sdk.png" Stretch="None"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>

                <!-- Status Block for providing messages to the user.  Use the
             NotifyUser() method to populate the message -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="StatusBlock" Grid.Row="2" Margin="12, 10, 12, 10" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Mainpage.xaml.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> picItems_;

        private ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> PicItems
        {
            get
            {
                return picItems_;
            }
            set
            {
                picItems_ = value;
            }

        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            picItems_ = AdaptItem.AdaptList();
            this.DataContext = PicItems;
        }
```

AdaptTemplate.cs for filling the AdaptGrid:

```
 public class AdaptItem
    {
        public String Image
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> AdaptList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> pics = new ObservableCollection<AdaptItem>()
        {
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/01.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/02.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/03.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/04.jpg"
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = "Assets/05.jpg"
            }
        };

        return pics;
    }
```

Comment: instead of `Assets/05.jpg` try `ms-appx:///Assets/05.jpg`

Comment: Still not working, not sure if im doing databinding right here or if its a problem with th UWPToolkit

Comment: From your code, you did not set the `ItemsSource` of the `AdaptiveGridView`. Please try to set `PicItems` to it that the image will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your approach is that you're setting the data context of the whole view instead of setting the `ItemSource` of the `AdaptivePanel`.

Just replace the below code:

```
this.DataContext = PicItems;
```

with:

`AdaptiveGridViewControl.ItemsSource = PicItems;`

For the above thing to work, please make sure you name your control instead of as `Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"` to `x:Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"`

the `x:` helps to use the controls in code behind for the controls that aren't a part of `UWP` default controls.

That being said, I would highly recommend you use `x:bind` instead of the `Binding`. I could see that you'd tried in the data template. You weren't able to do so because you need `x:Bind` an image control to a `BitmapImage` and not a string. you can do so by specifying the AdaptItem as below:

```
public class AdaptItem
{
    public Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage Image { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> AdaptList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<AdaptItem> pics = new ObservableCollection<AdaptItem>()
        {
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/01.jpg"))
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/02.png"))
            },
            new AdaptItem
            {
                Image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/03.png"))
            },
        };

        return pics;
    }
}
```

and your `DataTemplate` is as below:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AdaptTemplate" x:DataType="local:AdaptItem">
        <Grid
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
            <Image
                Source="{x:Bind Image}"
                Stretch="UniformToFill"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

---

That being said, i would also recommend using `DataBinding` to set your `ItemSource`.

Comment: I would never suggest creating BitmapImages in the viewmodel. Youcan do this with x:Bind by doing <Image><Image.Source><BitmapImage UriSource={x:Bind Uri} /></Image.Source><Image>, or forgo x:Bind entirely in this case as you'll get automatic DecodePixel optimisations by not explicitly specifying the BitmapImage yourself.

Comment: @UWP12 has the issue been resolved by this answer? if yes could you please mark my answer as correct (or even upvote it, if you liked the approach) so that this thread will be closed?